# Windows 7 Webcam recording software

Tags: windows-7, video, webcam, thinkpad

I want to record a video on my webcam on Lenovo T61 powered by Windows 7 Professional. I've noticed it's working differently from Windows XP. Can anyone care to recommend a decent webcam software that I can use for recording video?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I find the best and quickest program to be [Microsoft AMcap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373424(VS.85).aspx).

It works via native DirectX functions and is very lightweight.

It is a free utility available through the [DirectX SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=3021d52b-514e-41d3-ad02-438a3ba730ba)

Comment: If it's publicly available I don't see a problem with it

Answer (score 17):

Loads of apps out there. Here are a few alternatives:

- VLC: If you already have VLC media player, it can record from your webcam directly into a video file.  See [this page](http://gofree.com/Tutorials/VLCVideoWebcam.php) for how it's done.
- OneNote: Part of Microsoft Office, it records video into the current notebook.
- [Google's Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) See [this tutorial.](http://blog.ipevo.com/?p=2628)

Comment: Picasa --> can capture photos and videos with your webcam.

Comment: You don't need a tutorial. All you need to know is that there is a button in Picasa's toolbar which looks like a webcam with a little arrow. Fifth button to the right of the "Import" button, in my version 3.9.0.

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft Movie Maker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-live/movie-maker-get-started) - press the "webcam video" button

Comment: Mimimalistic answer, but the Movie Maker should really be able to do that...