# Looking for free video recording software to record video taken with laptop webcam

Tags: video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 Webcam recording software](https://superuser.com/questions/181983/windows-7-webcam-recording-software)

Pretty self-explanatory. I need to record some videos on my laptop using the webcam built into it with audio.

If anybody can please recommend some free software to do this I would appreciate it!

Comment: You may want to mention the OS you are looking to use it on.

Comment: It is for Windows 7 so it may be a duplicate, my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the software that comes with webcams has this capability nowadays.  I know that both my Logitech and Microsoft webcams do.  If it wasn't pre-installed, check the driver disks that came with the laptop, or go to the webcam manufacturer's website (if you can identify it) and see if they have software you can download for this capability.

Comment: This has to be setup on a lot of different laptops of different makes and models so I need a 3rd party solution. Thanks for the input however.